# Outlook 2007 - why can't I delete a personal folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, pst

A while ago, I consolidated multiple personal folders (`.pst`) into a single `.pat` file in Outlook 2007. This worked without a hitch.

I had 2 old `.pst` files, one named `personal-2006.pst`. I had an Outlook Mail folder, named `Personal-2006` pointing to this `.pst` file. While cleaning up, I deleted (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>) this `.pst` file. At the time I deleted it, Outlook was not running and the file successfully deleted.

However, the next time I started up Outlook, it still showed the mail folder `Personal-2006`. So I thought that maybe I had to close out of that mail folder, which I didn't do before deleting the `.pst` file. But when I try to close this mail folder, Outlook gives me an error that the file path to `personal-2006.pst` is not valid, so I can't remove the `Personal-2006` mail folder from my Outlook folders.

So far, I've tried creating an other `.pst` file and renaming it to `personal-2006.pst`, but that doesn't work because Outlook says the file is not valid, and I've tried running file recovery software, but none of the file recovery software can find `.pst` files in Outlook.

Has anyone been able to resolve a similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File -> Data File Management.
Find the Personal-2006 and remove it.  If it is the Default, you will have to change the default to another file, restart, and then remove it.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am not sure how I missed it. Thanks again.

Comment: Can't change the default to another file.